# Extract column value based on row index

Tags: r, for-loop

please help a newbie here. I want to extract the TOTAL_SITE information from the sites1 data frame. The data frame looks like:

```
FACILITY TOTAL_SITE
A        100
B        80
C        20

if(nrow(sites1) > 0){
  outStr <- "<ul>"
  for(site in sites1$FACILITY){
    outStr <- paste0(outStr,"<li>",site,": ", sites1$TOTAL_SITE, "</li>")
  }
  outStr <- paste0(outStr, "</ul>")
} else {
  outStr <- ""
}
```

However, the result shows repeatedly printing lines and indicates that I shouldn't loop through sites1$FACILITY and sites1$TOTAL_SITE concurrently. How can I use the index (row number) that will be corresponding to both columns of the sites1 data frame?

Comment: Try `desired <- sites1$TOTAL_SITE`

Answer (score 0):

This will get the TOTAL_SITE data from the df (not sure if this is what you mean?)

```
 TotalSiteData<-sites1["TOTAL_SITE"]
```

But this should keep corresponding row numbers and the data you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to make an HTML unordered list from TOTAL_SITE column, correct? Hopefully this solves your problem:

```
total_site <- sites1[,"TOTAL_SITE"]

outStr <- sapply(total_site, function(value){
    paste("<li>", value, "</li>", sep = "")
})

outStr <- paste("<ul>", outStr, "</ul>")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are asking for:

```
if(nrow(sites1) > 0)
    outStr <- paste0("<ul>",
            paste0("<li>", sites1$FACILITY, ": ", sites1$TOTAL_SITE, "</li>",collapse=""),
            "</ul>"
        )
else
    outStr <- ""
```

This code will take your data.frame's columns and paste them together by rows, assigning `outStr` the following character vector in your example:

`<ul><li>A: 100</li><li>B: 80</li><li>C: 20</li></ul>`